# emberjs loading spinner with findRecord

Tags: ember.js, promise, ember-data

EmberJS 3.4

I'm loading a Project entity from a backend which takes a couple of seconds. Now I would like to show a spinner during loading.

as described I created a project-loading.hbs (also tried with loading.hbs) https://guides.emberjs.com/release/routing/loading-and-error-substates/

project model class:

```
export default AuthenticatedRoute.extend({
  model(params) {
    return this.store.findRecord("project", params.projectname);
  },

  actions: {
    refresh: function() {
      this.refresh();
    }
  }
});
```

though it takes time to load the entity, the loading template seems not to be rendered/shown. Am I doing something wrong ?

Comment: Where did you put your `loading.hbs`? It should be in your templates folder.

Comment: yes, I've put it in the templates folder. when I use this.store.queryRecord instead of findRecord the spinner works. unfortunately queryRecord does not fit my needs.

Comment: And by the way, its name should be `loading.hbs`, in your question you said you've created a `project-loading.hbs` file. If so, you can try changing its name too.

Comment: thx for mentioning the loading.hbs. I already tried this too, no luck.

Answer (score 0):

For a route called `project` (`routes/project.js`), the loading template should be called `project-loading.hbs`.

I cloned your project and actually made it work (Ember CLI 3.4.3) by adding `templates/project-loading.hbs`, adding a `sleep(30)` call to your `/api/projects/:name` endpoint and going to a URL like `http://localhost:4200/projects/hallo`.

Do you have the problem when transitioning to the route internally (by using `transitionTo` or the `{{link-to}}` helper with a model for instance) or by entering the URL manually? Note that `model` hook is not executed when you transition to a route and pass in a model context (see https://guides.emberjs.com/v3.4.0/routing/specifying-a-routes-model/).

Answer (score -1):

I ended up with adding the following code to the application adapter:

```js
// not very ember way of doing this, but quite simple :)
$(document).ajaxStart(() => {
  $('#spinner').removeClass('hide');
});

$(document).ajaxStop(() => {
  $('#spinner').addClass('hide');
});
```

I really would prefer doing it the ember way. for now, this seems to do the trick.

for anyone interested, here's the complete project: https://github.com/puzzle/mailbox-watcher/tree/master/frontend